# How Laravel interact with Database

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have been searching on google several days but can't find the solution. I wonder how laravel application open connection with mysql database.

Case1:

```
//open db connection
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
//does laravel close connection after done and open a new one when have new query?
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
//close connection
```

Case2:

```
//What will happen if we use \DB transaction (compare with case1)
\DB::beginTransaction();
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
\DB::commit();
```

Case3:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
\DB::table('test')->insert(['name' => Str::random(15)]);
\DB::rollback();

//3 query statements will be rollback? So do anything happen with the database or nothing?
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/illuminate/database, this is something which handles everything re. database under the hood. More specifically lookout https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connection.php to check whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer

Case1:

Both the queries will be using the same connection. Laravel uses one connection for one request (You can create multiple as well but by default it always uses one)

Case2:

You are manually committing the changes here which means you are creating check points inside a transaction. The committed changes cannot be rolled back. In this case also Laravel uses same connection which it created on boot.

Case3:

All three inserts will be rolled back

NOTE: `DB::beginTransaction()` has to have `DB::endTransaction()` to close the transaction.

NOTE: DB transactions are also queries like normal insert or select queries. In all the above cases, Laravel is just preparing the query and sending it to the Database using the connection it has.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but somethign is not what i want to know.

Comment: What else you wanna know?

Comment: Case1: One connection, but i wonder if laravel close connection after query 1 done, and reopen it when query2 start. Because i think that, holding the connection is a wastage

Comment: Case2:  i want to know, if i use the \db:begintransaction (case 1 not), the open-close connection mechanism is diffirent with case1 or not?

Comment: In Both the cases, Laravel doesn't close the connection. Closing and opening connections with authentication will be a costlier operation than holding a connection open. As soon as Laravel boots up, it creates a connection and keeps to itself. Transactions are also queries which are run inside the same connection.

Comment: Php process are not expected to run more than few seconds so holding a connection open till that is wiser than opening and closing it. Also Laravel doesn't know how many queries you are gonna run, so if Laravel open and closes for every query run, it will end up having a bigger trouble than normal.

Comment: Case3: i want to know, when i rollback, is there anything happen to my database or nothing? because i think that rollback should be roll back  to what is was before the transaction. But when i recheck, i found that something has changed, such as auto increment value

Comment: one thing maybe you are not right. That is "As soon as Laravel boots up, it creates a connection". I think that it only open a connection when i match a code that need to connect to db.

Comment: Regarding the last comment. yes it might. but in order for its own dependency injection to work, it will query the user object before hand i guess. Technically what you said is correct but this will happen before you get the control in your hand. 

Regarding case 3: Yes it does change the auto increment value in order to avoid giving same id to two transactions. Lets assume two connections have started two transactions with same id, who ever commits second will fail cos the id is already taken.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It help me a lot!